# What does $A \geq 0$ mean ? Here $A$ is a Matrix .

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what these inequalities mean ? I am sure $A \geq 0$ does not mean $A$ is a non-negative definite Matrix. Because if $A , B$ non-negative definite , $AB$ may not be non-negative definite .

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Do you have some more context? Where are these questions coming from? For example they could be elementwise inequalities with an elementwise product of matrices.

Comment: This question is coming from my professor. Her name is M. SUndari. Do you want anyother information ?@Rammus

Comment: Well I think it is best to ask them how they have defined these things. Otherwise we can only guess the meaning.

Comment: Yes I want guesses.  How can they be defined ?@Rammus

Comment: This is no longer a question about mathematics; it's a guessing game. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

If we define $$A \ge 0$$ to mean that each entry of $A$ is nonnegative, then at least the first three are true. I leave it to you to determine whether the fourth holds as well.

Anyhow, given this evidence, I suspect that the meaning is that every entry is nonnegative. Sigh.

Comment: For four how do you know that $B  \geq C$ ? @John Hughes

Comment: Good point. I don't know that, because it's not true. I guess I needed more caffeine before typing. Thanks!